# java web application for checking username and password exists in database

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am a starter in java.
I am trying to develop a web application to validate user name and password in mysql database.

When i run the program i am getting exception. can anyone help me to find out what is wrong in the below code.

```
index.jsp
*********

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
      <form method="post" action="database">
             <body>
        <h1>Enter user details</h1>
        <h2>Name</h2>
        <input type="text" name="t1" /><br>
        <h2>Password</h2>
        <input type="password" name="p1" /><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="b1">
            </body>
        </form>
</html>


c1.java
********


package model;

public class c1 {
    String name,password;

    public c1(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}


database.java
*************



package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


public class database extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(name = "db1")
    private DataSource db1;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String name=request.getParameter("t1").trim();
            String password=request.getParameter("p1").trim();



          int value=select(name,password);

              if(value==1)
              {

                    out.println("User details present in database");

              }
              else
              {
                    out.println(value);
                    out.println("ERROR Invalid user");
              }



        } 

  catch(Exception e2)
            {
                out.println("error");
            }
finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);`
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";``
    }// </editor-fold>
public int select(String UserName,String Password) throws SQLException
   {
    DataSource d= db1;
       Connection c=d.getConnection();
       PreparedStatement p=c.prepareStatement
               ("select * from Employee where name='"+UserName+"' and password='"+Password+"'");

     ResultSet rs=p.executeQuery();
    int a= rs.getRow();
    return a;

   } 
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: exception stack trace please? and next time onwards please make sure that you put it in the post:)

Comment: This is not appropriate, put your <body> tag outside the <form> tag.

Comment: What exception will be thrown then? Please provide the stack trace of it...

Comment: I guess you should check that `request.getParameter("t1")` returns not null, and only then do `.trim()`

Comment: It is printing error in catch block. I have corrected everything you mentioned. whether there is any mistake in the logic?

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code:

JSP. Incorrect position of body tags:

Correct code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="database">>
    <h1>Enter user details</h1>
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="t1" />
    <br>
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input type="password" name="p1" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="b1">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVA. You have a couple of errors in your controller. Some ` characters producing errors.

Correct code:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
IOException {
    processRequest(request, response); // ERROR Removed last `
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description"; // ERROR removed lasts ``
}// </editor-fold>
```

WEB.XML: Check your web.xml and verify that you have the next lines:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Database-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.database</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Database-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/database</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It is printing error in the catch block. I have corrected everything you mentioned. whether there is any mistake in the logic?

Comment: Could you show us the error?, it's hard to tell :). Add on top of `out.println("error")` the next code `e2.printStackTrace()` and run it again.

Comment: I mean, once we enter details in jsp page (login form), the program is not executing the try block in the servlet. it is directly executing catch block and printing 'error' defined there. I think there is some error in the logic.

Comment: In order to access the catch block there has to exist an exception in the try block. If you add the line I commented before it will give us more information about what's going on.